# is there a way I replace all html code with a modified version of said code with chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I an making an google chrome extension that replaces some code under a `script` tag on a website when you visit said website. I already have the manifest.json file triggering the `content_scripts` when you visit the specified website, but I need to know how I could replace the whole sites html code with my new code. I thought about using `document.write` but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

`document.body.innerHTML = '<h1>hello</h1>'` . 
This will replace the all content of the `<body>`

Comment: Thank you but I have a question, could you replace document.body.innerHTML with for ex. document.head.innerHTML